# Unable to build a pdf output of "A Chapman & Hall/CRC Book" Example Using #bookdown package

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I am facing challenges in my attempt in using bookdown to render a pdf_book for Chapman & Hall/CRC variant

I followed exactly the guide by Yihui in his repo https://github.com/yihui/bookdown-crc, I cloned the repo and was able to render/build a gitbook output from my Rstudio IDE. However, when I tried to render a pdf_book output, I get the error prompt below. FYI - I have already installed TinyTex and other dependancies including Pandoc.

```
Quitting from lines 22-30 (bookdown.Rmd) 
Error in dev.control(displaylist = if (record) "enable" else
"inhibit") : dev.control() called without an open graphics device
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In (function (filename = if (onefile) "Rplots.pdf" else  
"Rplot%03d.pdf",  :
unable to load shared object   
'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library/grDevices/libs//
cairo.so':
dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library/grDevices/
libs//cairo.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libxcb-shm.0.dylib
Referenced from:

/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library/grDevices/libs//
cairo.so
Reason: image not found
2: In (function (filename = if (onefile) "Rplots.pdf" else  

"Rplot%03d.pdf",  :
failed to load cairo DLL
```

Comment: I don't know how you installed R (on macOS, presumably), but I'd strongly recommend that you install it via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh): `brew cask install r`. The grDevices package in your R installation seems to be broken.

Comment: @YihuiXie thank you very much for taking the time to help. You are right, machine is macOS. Following your recommendation, I have re-installed r via Homebrew, however this did not address the problem.